# Pass a string to the GCC compiler from a Python build script

Tags: python, gcc

The project assembly script is written in Python, I do not speak Python myself, it was taken from a demo project. I need to pass a string to the GCC compiler - a short git hash of the project version. I get the line itself in the script like this.

```
def get_git_revision_short_hash() -> str:
    return subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD']).decode('ascii').strip()

GIT_REV = get_git_revision_short_hash()

print(GIT_REV)
```

the control print outputs exactly what is needed. I'm trying to pass a string to the compiler like this

```
CFLAGS += ' -DGIT_REV=' + GIT_REV
```

I use this in my project:

```
LOG_I("Git Revision:%s", GIT_REV);
```

where LOG_I is an rt-thread macro that outputs messages to the UART.

The compiler gives an error:

```
<command-line>: error: 'fa23128' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

fa23128 - hash of the git version of the project.

python version 3

Full text of the script:

```
import os
import subprocess

def get_git_revision_short_hash() -> str:
    return subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD']).decode('ascii').strip()



# toolchains options
ARCH='arm'
CPU='cortex-a'
CROSS_TOOL='gcc'

if os.getenv('RTT_CC'):
    CROSS_TOOL = os.getenv('RTT_CC')

# only support GNU GCC compiler.
PLATFORM    = 'gcc'
EXEC_PATH   = r'/usr/bin'
GIT_REV = get_git_revision_short_hash()

print(GIT_REV)

if os.getenv('RTT_EXEC_PATH'):
    EXEC_PATH = os.getenv('RTT_EXEC_PATH')
EXEC_PATH = '/home/rain/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10/bin'

BUILD = 'debug'

if PLATFORM == 'gcc':
    # toolchains
    PREFIX = 'arm-none-eabi-'
    CC = PREFIX + 'gcc'
    CXX = PREFIX + 'g++'
    AS = PREFIX + 'gcc'
    AR = PREFIX + 'ar'
    LINK = PREFIX + 'gcc'
    TARGET_EXT = 'elf'
    SIZE = PREFIX + 'size'
    OBJDUMP = PREFIX + 'objdump'
    OBJCPY = PREFIX + 'objcopy'
    STRIP = PREFIX + 'strip'

    #DEVICE = ' -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a7 -marm -msoft-float '
    DEVICE = ' -mcpu=cortex-a7 -marm -msoft-float '    
    #DEVICE = ' -march=armv7-a'
    CFLAGS = DEVICE + ' -Wall' #+ ' -mfpu=neon-vfpv4' + ' -mfloat-abi=hard'
    AFLAGS = ' -c' + DEVICE + ' -x assembler-with-cpp -D__ASSEMBLY__ -I.'
    LINK_SCRIPT = 'link.lds'
    LFLAGS = DEVICE + ' -nostartfiles -Wl,--gc-sections,-Map=rtthread.map,-cref,-u,system_vectors'+\
                      ' -T %s' % LINK_SCRIPT

    CPATH = ''
    LPATH = ''

    # generate debug info in all cases
    AFLAGS += ' -gdwarf-2'
    CFLAGS += ' -g -gdwarf-2'

    if BUILD == 'debug':
        CFLAGS += ' -Ofast'
    else:
        CFLAGS += ' -O2'
        
    #CFLAGS += ' -DGIT_REV="' + GIT_REV + '"'

    CXXFLAGS = CFLAGS + ' -Woverloaded-virtual -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti'

    M_CFLAGS = CFLAGS + ' -mlong-calls -fPIC '
    M_CXXFLAGS = CXXFLAGS + ' -mlong-calls -fPIC'
    M_LFLAGS = DEVICE + CXXFLAGS + ' -Wl,--gc-sections,-z,max-page-size=0x4' +\
                                    ' -shared -fPIC -nostartfiles -nostdlib -static-libgcc'
    M_POST_ACTION = STRIP + ' -R .hash $TARGET\n' + SIZE + ' $TARGET \n'

    POST_ACTION = OBJCPY + ' -O binary $TARGET rtthread.bin\n' +\
                  SIZE + ' $TARGET \n'
```

How to correctly pass this string to the GCC compiler?

Comment: How are you generating the command to gcc?  You haven't shown that part.

Comment: `to pass a string to the compiler like this` So where do you pass it? Where is `gcc` called? Did you consider using a build system, like cmake, scons, bazel? Bazel is even in python.

Comment: i use build system scons